# Rails URL helper for sorting filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

I have a table **Companies** with field **city_id**. I need in sorting companies by cities. I do next:

```
# companies_controller.rb
def sort_by_city
  @cities = City.joins(:company).uniq
  @companies = Company.where("city_id = ?", params[:city_id])
  render 'index'
end

# routes.rb:
get '/companies/city/:city_id', to: 'companies#sort_by_city'
```

and in index.html.erb I try make links for this filter:

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
  <li><%= link_to city.name, UNKNOWN_path(city.id) %> (<%= city.companies_count %>) 
<% end %>
```

I want links like this: "*www.site.com/companies/city/23*"
What I must write instead of UNKNOWN_path? Or I do something wrong before (in controller or in routes.rb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to your route with the `as` option :

For example :

```
get '/companies/city/:city_id', to: 'companies#sort_by_city', as: 'companies_city_sort'
```

And then use

```
companies_city_sort_path
```

Also, have a look at [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), it may be more adapted.

Comment: Great thanks! I read guid "Resource Routing" more then 3 times only today. But I realy noob in rails now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you type `rake routes` in your terminal you can find the name of the current path.

Just look for the line where `companies#sort_by_city` is listed.

Comment: I saw `companies#sort_by_city`, but I don't know how to use this knowledge

Comment: at the left side on this line there is the pathname specified. You just have to append `_path`

Comment: It was empty before `             GET    /companies/city/:city_id(.:format) companies#sort_by_city`

Comment: ok, then you have to specify it with `as: ...`. But usually it often helps to look at `rake routes` output.